# Vi - "pop" explanations for reserved words and functions

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, vi

I'm in the process of learning a new programing language ([Neuron](http://www.neuron.yale.edu/)), and it so happens that it has many language-specific reserved words.

I was wondering if there is a way to configure Vi to emulate some graphical code editors that pop a small window with the function doc when hovering over such a function that has it configured.

Ideally (and I might be just day dreaming but *it is* Vi so it is worth asking) - 
When the cursor is over a word or a function name I would like to press some key sequence and have a pre-configured text to show up in Vi's command line.

[image: Desired behaviour mockup]

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this; it's a little simplistic, but a good starting point:

```
function! ShowExplanation( word )
    if a:word ==# 'reserved'
        echo "explanation"
    elseif a:word ==# 'text'
        echo "another explanation"
    else
        echo
    endif
endfunction
nnoremap <silent> <Leader><Leader> :call ShowExplanation(expand('<cword>'))<CR>
```

Other ideas would be to use the `CursorHold` event to automatically show this when you pause, or use of the *preview window* to show longer explanations.

Comment: Seems like an elegant and simple to implement solution. Thanks!